# Complex Fourier Series of $\cosh(x)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> The real series already is covered in this world, but I had to
> compute the complex Series of this one:
>
> $f(t) = \cosh(t)\quad t\in(-\pi,\pi]$
>
> Here I wondered why $-\pi$ is not in the boundary, but I included it
> anyway:
>
> $\displaystyle{f(t) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}} c_n\,e^{i\,n\,t}$
>
> The trouble started with calculating $c_n$:

**Edit I:** thanks to a remark the solution *should* be alright now.

**Edit II** in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$

$\begin{align} 
c_n 
& =\dfrac{1}{2\,\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cosh(t)\,e^{-i\,n\,t} \mathrm{dt}  =\dfrac{1}{4\,\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{t(1-i\,n)}+e^{-t\,(1+i\,n)}\,\mathrm{dt} \\\\
& = \dfrac{1}{4\,\pi} \left[\dfrac{e^{t}\,e^{-i\,n\,t}}{1-i\,n}-\dfrac{e^{-t}\,e^{-i\,n\,t}}{1+i\,n}\right]_{-\pi}^{+\pi} \\\\
&=\dfrac{1}{4\,\pi}\left[e^{-i\,n\,\pi}\left(\dfrac{e^{\pi}}{1-i\,n}-\dfrac{e^{-\pi}}{1+i\,n}\right)+e^{i\,n\,\pi}\left(\dfrac{e^{\pi}}{1+i\,n}-\dfrac{e^{-\pi}}{1-i\,n}\right)\right]\\\\\\
& =\dfrac{1}{4\,\pi}\left[e^{-i\,n\,\pi}\left(\dfrac{\color{red}{\color{blue}{2}\,\sinh(\pi)}+\color{blue}{2}\,i\,n\,\cosh(\pi)}{1+n^2}\right)+e^{i\,n\,\pi}\left(\dfrac{\color{blue}{2}\,\color{red}{\sinh(\pi)}-\color{blue}{2}\,i\,n\,\cosh(\pi)}{1+n^2}\right)\right]\\\\\\
& = \dfrac{1}{4\,\pi}\,\dfrac{\color{blue}{2}\,i\,n\,\cosh(\pi)}{1+n^2}\,\left[\cos(-n\,\pi)+i\,\sin(-n\,\pi)-\cos(n\,\pi)-i\,\sin(n\,\pi)\right]\\ \\
& +\dfrac{1}{4\,\pi}\,\dfrac{\color{red}{\color{blue}{2}\,\sinh(\pi)}}{1+n^2}\,\left[\cos(-n\,\pi)+i\,\sin(-n\,\pi)\color{red}{+}\cos(n\,\pi)\color{red}{+}i\,\sin(n\,\pi)\right]\\\\
& = \dfrac{1}{4\,\pi}\,\left(\dfrac{\color{blue}{4}\,n\,\cosh(\pi)}{1+n^2}\,\sin(n\,\pi)+\color{red}{\dfrac{\color{blue}{4}\,\sinh(\pi)}{1+n^2}\,\cos(n\,\pi)}\right)
\end{align}$

Finally this is now identical with a programs answer.

> Programs answer:
> $c_n =
>  \dfrac{1}{2\,\pi}\,\left(\dfrac{2\,n\,\cosh(\pi)}{1+n^2}\,\sin(n\,\pi)+{\dfrac{2\,\sinh(\pi)}{1+n^2}\,\cos(n\,\pi)}\right)$

---

Also: Since there are no poles to consider this expression can be simplified for all integers:

$c_n = {\dfrac{1}{\pi}\,\dfrac{\sinh(\pi)}{1+n^2}\,(-1)^n}$

Furthermore you can deduce real coefficients by setting:

$\begin{align}
&\displaystyle{a_0 = \lim_{n \to 0}c_n} \quad &\Rightarrow& \quad a_0 = \dfrac{\sinh(\pi)}{\pi} \\\\
&\displaystyle{a_n =+ 2\,\texttt{real($c_n)$}} &\Rightarrow& \quad a_n = {2\,\dfrac{1}{\pi}\,\dfrac{\sinh(\pi)}{1+n^2}\,(-1)^n} \\\\
&\displaystyle{b_n = -2\,\texttt{imag($c_n)$}} &\Rightarrow& \quad b_n = 0
\end{align}$

All in all the Fourier Series can be compiled as:

$f(t) = \displaystyle{\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}{\dfrac{1}{\pi}\,\dfrac{\sinh(\pi)}{1+n^2}\,(-1)^n}\,e^{i\,n\,t}}$

or

$f(t) = \displaystyle{\dfrac{\sinh(\pi)}{\pi} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{2\,\dfrac{1}{\pi}\,\dfrac{\sinh(\pi)}{1+n^2}\,(-1)^n}}\,\cos(n\,t)$

Comment: of course $\sin(n\pi)=0$, so what you got is $c_n=0$ (and the answer you got from that program is very strangely written, including that first term that vanishes...)

Comment: How did you get $\frac{e^\pi}{1-in}-\frac{e^{-\pi}}{1+in}=\frac{in\cosh(\pi)}{1+n^2}$???

Comment: But isn't the programs answer fundamentally different? It includes a non vanishing term (the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ one). I've got this result by summing up: $\dfrac{e^{\pi}}{1-i\,n}-\dfrac{e^{-\pi}}{1+i\,n} = \dfrac{e^{\pi}\,(1+i\,n)-e^{-\pi}(1-i\,n)}{(1-i\,n)\,(1+i\,n)} = \dfrac{e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi}+i\,n\,(e^{\pi}+e^{-\pi})}{1+n^2}$. Yep and right there is my fault: I wrongly thought $e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi} = 0$. Good call

Comment: I'll incorporate that insight in my edits later on. I'll hope it'll be alright then.

Comment: Can you find the error?  Still not totally right, but close to.

Comment: Presumably another error in the algebra. You can find it as well as we can - look at **every** step vary carefully. So why are you asking us to fix your work for you?

Comment: you are more talented though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the missing $2$ comes from the fact that you forgot the factor $2$ when converting from exponential form of a hyperbolic, back to its direct form. In particular, in the following computation
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{e^{\pi}}{1-in} \color{blue}-  \frac{e^{\color{blue}- \pi}}{1\color{blue}+ in} &= \frac{(e^\pi - e^{-\pi}) + in(e^\pi + e^{-\pi})}{1 + n^2} \\
&= \frac{\color{red}{2}\sinh(\pi) + \color{red}{2}in\cosh(\pi)}{1 + n^2}
\end{align}
$$
and the other one, since
$$
\sinh(x) = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2} \qquad \cosh(x) = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}.
$$
Carrying this along will fix the error.

Comment: thank you so much! I was blind on both eyes, could habe been searching for ages.

Comment: @Leon Not a problem. Glad I could help. These things happen, so no worries.